# Include directive depending on Qt version

Tags: c++, qt, include, c-preprocessor

I need to include the following header in my code:

```
#include <5.4.1/QtGui/private/qzipwriter_p.h>
```

The problem is, we are compiling this on other Qt versions, such as 5.4.2 or 5.5.x

I know I should not use these "private" headers since they are unsupported, but we need them at least until we have a durable replacement.

How can I concatenate the `QT_VERSION_STR` variable in the path so that this works with all versions?

Comment: Did you try ``#include <QtGui/private/qzipwriter_p.h>``? Wouldn't that just include the once required of your current Qt installation? If you need it to be just this one file just include the constant path (set in environment variable for example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compare numeric `QT_VERSION` macro using human readable helper [`QT_VERSION_CHECK`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#QT_VERSION_CHECK) that combines major, minor and patch numbers into `QT_VERSION` format:

```
#if QT_VERSION == QT_VERSION_CHECK(5, 4, 1)
//...
#endif
```

---

The idea for concatenation taken from GCC headers [C Macro - Dynamic #include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873722/c-macro-dynamic-include)

The problem is that we do not have macro tokens with Qt major, minor and patch versions. There is only numeric `QT_VERSION`. So, it is tricky to get required numbers. It is possible to transfer them as macro definitions from `.pro` file using `qmake` variables [`QT_*_VERSION`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#qt-major-version):

```
DEFINES += QT_MAJOR_VERSION=$$QT_MAJOR_VERSION
DEFINES += QT_MINOR_VERSION=$$QT_MINOR_VERSION
DEFINES += QT_PATCH_VERSION=$$QT_PATCH_VERSION
```

Now those macro versions can be used in source files:

```
// To return as a string: "5.4.1/QtGui/private/qzipwriter_p.h"
#define qt_header__(x) #x
#define qt_header_(major,minor,patch) qt_header__(major.minor.patch/QtGui/private/qzipwriter_p.h)
#define qt_header(major,minor,patch) qt_header_(major,minor,patch)

// Simpler without stringification, however Qt Creator cannot follow
// that header
#define qt_header(major,minor,patch) <major.minor.patch/QtGui/private/qzipwriter_p.h>

#include qt_header(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, QT_MINOR_VERSION, QT_PATCH_VERSION)
```

It is better to use stringified variant (`"5.4.1/QtGui/private/qzipwriter_p.h"`). In that case the latest versions of Qt Creator can follow such `qt_header()` macro and highlight text accordingly.

Comment: No idea for concatenating the version string in the path?

Comment: @galinette No, it is possible to concatenate macro tokens but not strings http://stackoverflow.com/a/20551609/4023446 To use that you need to have not a string but something like `#define VER 5.4.1`. Then it is possible to generate include path from such `VER` macro.

Comment: @galinette I updated the answer with possible concatenation.

Comment: There is a version string in Qt, it is `QT_VERSION_STR`, as in the question. It is exactly equal to "major.minor.patch", at least in Qt 4 and 5

Comment: @galinette `QT_VERSION_STR` is a string. It is defined as `#define QT_VERSION_STR "5.4.1"`, but you need it without quotation.

Comment: Ah, that's the reason why I could not use it for this purpose

Answer (score 4):

Use `QT_VERSION` instead:

> QT_VERSION
>   This macro expands a numeric value of the form 0xMMNNPP (MM = major, NN = minor, PP = patch) that specifies Qt's version number.

```
#if QT_VERSION == 0x050401
  #include <5.4.1/QtGui/private/qzipwriter_p.h>
#endif
```

**Edit:**

> No idea for concatenating the version string in the path?

The standard doesn't allow that (16.3.4/3):

> The resulting completely macro-replaced preprocessing token sequence is not processed as a preprocessing
>   directive even if it resembles one

So you can't make a macro that will be expanded into an `#include` directive. You also can't use a macro inside the brackets of `include` (`#include <like this>`) because everything inside the brackets is just a string.

Comment: No idea for concatenating the version string in the path?

Comment: @galinette, you could possibly do it with some nasty tricks, but generally, no.

Answer (score 0):

With cmake it would be like this:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Qml)
add_definitions(-DQT_VERSION_MAJOR=${Qt5_VERSION_MAJOR})
add_definitions(-DQT_VERSION_MINOR=${Qt5_VERSION_MINOR})
add_definitions(-DQT_VERSION_PATCH=${Qt5_VERSION_PATCH})
```

yourcode.cpp:

```
#define p_qqmljslexer(major,minor,patch)  <major.minor.patch/QtQml/private/qqmljslexer_p.h>

#include p_qqmljslexer(QT_VERSION_MAJOR, QT_VERSION_MINOR, QT_VERSION_PATCH)
```

Answer (score 0):

With two letter minor_version e.g. 5.11 not works but it does

```
#if QT_VERSION >= QT_VERSION_CHECK(5, 11, 0)
    auto isok = f.open(QIODevice::NewOnly| QIODevice::Text);
#else
    auto isok = !QFileInfo::exists(newfile) && f.open(QIODevice::Text);
#endif
```