# C Preprocessor to compute product specific include

Tags: macros, c-preprocessor, generic-programming, stringification

I have to maintain C code that has both generic components and product specific components. I would like to simplify my code so that I have just one generic **product.h** file which has a structure like

```
#if (PRODUCT_ID == 1)
    #define PRODUCT_NAME Product1
#else
    #if (PRODUCT_ID == 2)
        #define PRODUCT_NAME Product2
    #else
        #error "Unsupported product id"
    #endif
#endif
```

Then, whenever I have a header **foo.h** which has product specific components, I would like to use syntax like this

```
#include "product.h"
#include PRODUCT_SPECIFIC_INCLUDE
```

where `PRODUCT_SPECIFIC_INCLUDE` should be derived from `__FILE__` and `PRODUCT_NAME` macro in such a way that it would translate to

```
#include "Product1/foo.h"
```

that is, the product specific header file has the same filename as the generic file, but is located in a product specific folder, whose name is the value of `PRODUCT_NAME` macro.

It seems that whatever I try has preprocessor stringification issues. I can't be the first to want such a structure. What am I missing?

**Update**

Here is what I currently have for `PRODUCT_SPECIFIC_INCLUDE` which does not work

```
#define TOKENPASTE(x, y) x ## y
#define TOKENPASTE2(x, y) TOKENPASTE(x, y)
#define PRODUCT_SPECIFIC_INCLUDE TOKENPASTE2(PRODUCT_SPECIFIC, __FILE__)
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to do with the standard C preprocessor. You might have to do it in the build environment instead.

Comment: Please show the macro related to `PRODUCT_SPECIFIC_INCLUDE`

Comment: Here is what I currently have for `PRODUCT_SPECIFIC_INCLUDE` which does not work <code>#define TOKENPASTE(x, y) x ## y
#define TOKENPASTE2(x, y) TOKENPASTE(x, y)
#define PRODUCT_SPECIFIC_INCLUDE TOKENPASTE2(PRODUCT_SPECIFIC, __FILE_\_)</code>

Comment: It would be better to add it to the question body as it is the important part.

Comment: This may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873722/c-macro-dynamic-include

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like

```
#define STR2(F) #F
#define STR(F) STR2(F)
#define MAKE_PRODUCT_INCLUDE(FILE) STR(PRODUCT_SPECIFIC/FILE)

#include MAKE_PRODUCT_INCLUDE(foo.h)
```

but I don't know a way to avoid repeating the file name.  Using `__FILE__` gives a string and there is no way that I know to concatenate strings in the preprocessor (the fact that juxtaposed strings are concatenated is a parser feature, and `##` is not usable for that "foo""bar" is not the spelling of a valid token).

Answer (score 0):

The first code could be reduced to:

```
#if (PRODUCT_ID == 1)
    #define PRODUCT_NAME Product1
#elif (PRODUCT_ID == 2)
    #define PRODUCT_NAME Product2
#else
    #error "Unsupported product id"
#endif
```

Secondly, you are trying to get the required include header name but the problem is in these two lines:

```
#define TOKENPASTE(x, y) x ## y
#define PRODUCT_SPECIFIC_INCLUDE TOKENPASTE2(PRODUCT_SPECIFIC, __FILE__)
```

> `__FILE__` : **This macro expands** to the name of the current input file,
>   **in the form of a C string constant**

`TOKENPASTE(PRODUCT_SPECIFIC, __FILE__)` **|-->**  `product ## "foo.h"`

`product` and `"` can never give a valid token. And that's why the CPP gives you error. What you need is writing the **filename as plaintext** so you can combine it with other macros.

You can do it like this:

```
#define TOKENPASTE(x) #x
#define TOKENPASTE2(x) TOKENPASTE(x)
#define PRODUCT_SPECIFIC_INCLUDE TOKENPASTE2(PRODUCT_SPECIFIC/foo.h)
#include PRODUCT_SPECIFIC_INCLUDE
```