# how to append to __FILE__ at preprocessor time and include the result

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I want to include `component.h.gen` from `component.h`.

I've already seen that I can use `__FILE__` with `#include` and that results in recursive inclusion if there is no header guard.

Is there a way to append a C string literal and include the result? This is what I've tried so far:

```
#define CAT_IMPL(s1, s2) s1##s2
#define CAT(s1, s2) CAT_IMPL(s1, s2)
#define DO_IT CAT(__FILE__, ".gen")

#include DO_IT
```

But this results in the same recursion with the file including itself - the `".gen"` part is not used - and I get this warning with MSVC:

> warning C4067: unexpected tokens following preprocessor directive - expected a newline

Is there a solution that would work with gcc/clang/msvc?

Note that I'm planning on using this in hundreds if not thousands of files and I would like to simplify my life by just copy-pasting the same code - that's why I'm trying to get this to work.

Comment: downvoters - please explain...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible:

- `__FILE__` expands to a string; you cannot unstringify a string.  So the technique of just adding the "rest" of the string, then stringifying the result, isn't available.
- Pasting two string tokens does not create a valid token.  So pasting isn't available.
- String literal concatenation doesn't exist for the preprocessor (preprocessor is translation phase 4; string literal concatenation is phase 6).

Comment: such a shame that I can't attach defines on header files and only on source files (but it makes sense though...) - otherwise I could simulate this with my build system...

Comment: Your build system is open ended... you could simply use another tool to generate the include files.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of obscure, but seems to be possible with gcc.

Look at the second answer of this question:

[C Macro - Dynamic #include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873722/c-macro-dynamic-include)

Comment: That question isn't relevant because you can't unstringify `__FILE__`.