# Is it possible to use some sort of path for #include?

Tags: c++

I have this bunch of #include statements in the file:

```
#include "/Users/cooper/Desktop/MyLib/graph_api.h"
#include "/Users/cooper/Desktop/MyLib/mst.h"
#include "/Users/cooper/Desktop/MyLib/dfs.h"
#include "/Users/cooper/Desktop/MyLib/bfs.h"
#include "/Users/cooper/Desktop/MyLib/topo_sort.h"
#include "/Users/cooper/Desktop/MyLib/scc.h"
#include "/Users/cooper/Desktop/MyLib/bipartite.h"
#include "/Users/cooper/Desktop/MyLib/dijkstra.h"
#include "/Users/cooper/Desktop/MyLib/union_find.h"
#include "/Users/cooper/Desktop/MyLib/my_string.h"
#include "/Users/cooper/Desktop/MyLib/2d_array.h"
```

It might change, though, in the future and I'll have to update a number of lines. Is it possible to have something like

```
PATH = "/Users/cooper/Desktop/MyLib/
#include PATH + "2d_array.h"
```

?

Comment: It is not a part of the makefile per se. It is a command line option. Makefile is just one mechanism to manage compiling

Comment: It looks like you're on an OSX system (judging by the paths) which means you are probably using Xcode. In the project settings there must be a place you can enter preprocessor settings, like adding include paths. If you do that, and add `/Users/cooper/Desktop/MyLib` then you can simply do `#include <2d_array.h>`.

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743822/generate-include-file-name-in-a-macro) should be useful for you. (I mean wrtie `#define PATH "/Users/cooper/Desktop/MyLib/` and `#include PATH "2d_array.h"`)

Comment: I am using XCode, right.

Answer (score 9):

Usually your compiler provides an option where you can add pathes where it looks up header files from `#include` statements.

E.g. for GCC add

```
-I/Users/cooper/Desktop/MyLib
```

to your compiler command line.

---

This option might also be available to be set in your IDE's project settings, or as a variable in your build system.